# How to validate dropdown list using validator in js

Tags: javascript, validation

I am trying to validate drop down in js. Here is my script code

```
$.validator.addMethod(
  'drop_down_validation',
  function (value, element) {
    alert ("my_fun")
    var val = $('#creative_offer_type').val();
    alert (val);
    if (value.length==0 && val=="") {
       return false;
    }
       else return true;
  },
  $.format("must select atleast one value")
);


var form_rules = {
    'creative[offer_type]' : {
                              required: true,
                              drop_down_validation: true
                            },

  };
  var form_messages = {
    'creative_offer_type' : { required: 'You must specify Offer Type'},
  };
```

Is is correct? I tried out like this, but doesn't show any response in UI.

Answer (score 0):

[For your reference](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/300252/how-to-validate-a-dropdownlist-using-javascript)

```
function JSFunctionValidate()
{
if(document.getElementById('<%=ddlView.ClientID%>').selectedIndex == 0)
{
alert("Please select ddl");
return false;
}
return true;
}
```

Just call this method in your dropdown..